# Python copyfile : IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, windows, copy, permission-denied, file-copying

Im getting IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, because I tested this on a other PC and on that PC the script is working.

This is the error I got:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\usr\Desktop\TEST\Test.py", line 81, in <module>
    _MyFunction(dir)
  File "D:\Users\usr\Desktop\TEST\Test.py", line 53, in _MyFunction
    copyfile("My Folder/Input/MyLog.log", "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\logs\Files\MyLog.log")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram\\logs\\Files\\MyLog.log'
```

This is my Python code:

```
copyfile("My Folder/Input/MyLog.log", "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\logs\Files\MyLog.log")
```

What I tried to fix it:

1. Give full permissions to all windows users on the folder and all files
2. Use the shutil.copy instead of shutil.copyfile
3. Run CMD as Administrator

So what can the problem be?

Comment: Does the directory in the destination path exist? Otherwise you need to create this before invoking `shutil.copy`.

Comment: If even an elevated administrator can't write to the destination file, then it's probably a sharing violation, e.g.  if the destination exists and is open in your process or another process without write sharing. That wouldn't be due to Python normally. `open` uses read and write sharing. But some programs are particular about sharing write access -- especially for log files.

Comment: Programs shouldn't be writing log files in "Program Files". Use a directory in `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, the user's folder for non-roaming application data. Or use a folder in `%PROGRAMDATA%` that you've made writable by all users (i.e. you have full control when you create a folder here, so you can add an ACE for the "Users" group via icacls.exe).

Comment: Avoid using unescaped backslashes in path literals. Preferably, use [r]aw strings, e.g. `r"C:\Program Files\MyProgram\logs\File\MyLog.log"`, or forward slashes.

Comment: I fixed the problem. 

Before the copyfile function I cleaned the folder. Some how Windows was not ready with removing the files. So thats why I got the IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied error. 

I added timer.sleep(5) between my delete folder function and my copyfile function.

Comment: You don't have to delete a file before overwriting it. But if you do delete it, it may still be linked in the directory even though it's flagged for deletion. It doesn't actually get unlinked until all handles are closed (sometimes malware scanners are a problem here), and you can't open a handle for any access if a file is flagged for deletion. That's probably why your `sleep(5)` works, but if this is the case it would require less delay to check `os.listdir` in a loop with a `sleep(0.1)` until the file is no longer in the listing.

Comment: For my case, closing the Spyder editor eliminated the permission issue.